# Why don't all VTCs come up in my queue?

Tags: support

Scenario:

- I look at my review queue. I have one Close Vote item. (Q1) It's for a possible duplicate.
- I act/skip/whatever. Refresh the queue and there are no items for review.
- I go to the front page and see a question (Q2) and click through. The question has an existing VTC. Comments indicate that the VTC occurred a short time before (not while I was scanning the front page).

Why was Q2 not already in my review queue if it had already received a VTC?

The Reopen queue exhibits similar behavior.

As of 10:14 AM EST, the question [Why didn’t the Kryptonians choose another planet in Man of Steel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/why-didn-t-the-kryptonians-choose-another-planet-in-man-of-steel) has one re-open vote. If I go to the review queue, there is nothing to be voted on. The [review history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history) also does not list any re-open votes for the question.

And... as of 12:41 PM EST (possibly sometime between 11:30 and now), the question is now in my review queue.

Answer (score 3):

If other people review the question in the queue, and vote to keep it open, it will drop out of the review queue.

[From meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/166646):

> Normally, a question must hit 100 views before close votes age away, so as to give enough folks time to see and review it. Questions with close votes stay in the review queue until they are closed or the votes expire.
>
> But if enough people (currently 3) select "Do Not Close" within the review queue, the question will be immediately removed from the queue (not shown to any more reviewers) and the aging starts immediately.

Additionally, in my experience, any time you see a question with close votes, and then go to the review queue, you won't see that question in the close queue.  I suspect that the system treats your visit as if you had already reviewed it.

Comment: I thought about that, but [the question in question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56098/where-to-start-the-books-when-you-are-watching-the-series) was so new at the time, I don't think it had had time to get three leave-opens yet. In fact, it's closed now.

Comment: You are correct; in fact, it [did not get any votes to leave it open](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/history).

Comment: @phantom42 Is it possible that you had seen the question after it received a close vote, but before looking in the queue?

Comment: It had one VTC when I viewed the question.

Comment: @phantom42 In my experience, any time you see a question with close votes, and then go to the review queue, you won't see that question there.  I suspect that the system treats your visit as if you had already reviewed it.

Comment: Right, but I had *just* refreshed the queue, gone to the front page and clicked through. The comments indicated that the first VTC was done before I had refreshed the queue.

Comment: @Beofett I just now went from a question that has close votes, to the close question queue, and that same question was there asking me to vote on it. This is a question I've been pretty active on today, having posted an answer, and commenting on another answer.

Comment: `I suspect that the system treats your visit as if you had already reviewed it.` - Not quite.  If you act upon it while viewing the question, then go to the review queue, it gives you the option "I'm Done" in place of "Skip".  I'm pretty sure I've also seen them in the queue after viewing the question even when I did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The question [was in the review queue 1 hour ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/history); with 3 reviewers:

```
NikolaiDante    Where to start the books ...    Close   1 hour ago
Ward            Where to start the books ...    Close   1 hour ago
Monty129        Where to start the books ...    Close   1 hour ago
```

Could it be that it was closed before you had a chance to see it in the review queue? It [was closed 13:56 GMT](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/56098/timeline), and those 3 reviewers from the queue were the last 3 of 5 VTCs; which means it has 2 VTCs before it even got to the review queue.

Comment: It had one VTC when I viewed the question.

Comment: @phantom42 - race condition! Or what Beofett said in his 20-second-ago-edit in the last paragraph.

Comment: Your comment about having two VTCs before it got to the queue is curious. Does the first VTC not send it to the queue automatically/immediately?

Comment: @phantom42 - to be honest, I have no idea. But even if it does, it could still be a race condition.